# UE4 crashes on launch when using custom components in C++?

Tags: c++, unreal-4

I created `SM_Door` in my Editor with a custom `Actor` class named "Door" to fire some events like open and close.

The problem is, when I open the UE4 Editor, it loads nearly to 75% loading and then crashes, and I really don't know why!

[image]

The code of the Door Header file is:

```
#pragma once
 #include "CoreMinimal.h"
 #include "Components/ActorComponent.h"
 #include "GameFramework/Actor.h"
 #include "Door.generated.h"

 UCLASS( ClassGroup=(Custom), meta=(BlueprintSpawnableComponent) )
 class MAZE_API UDoor : public UActorComponent
 {
     GENERATED_BODY()

 public:    
     // Sets default values for this component's properties
     UDoor();

     void Open();
     void Close();
     bool IsOverlapping(AActor*);

 protected:
     // Called when the game starts
     virtual void BeginPlay() override;

 public:    
     // Called every frame
     virtual void TickComponent(float DeltaTime, ELevelTick TickType, FActorComponentTickFunction* ThisTickFunction) override;

 };
```

Then I created Runner class representing the default player:

[image]

The full code of the Runner class is:

```
#pragma once

 #include "CoreMinimal.h"
 #include "Components/ActorComponent.h"
 #include "Engine/World.h"
 #include "Door.h"
 #include "GameFramework/Actor.h"
 #include "Runner.generated.h"


 UCLASS( ClassGroup=(Custom), meta=(BlueprintSpawnableComponent) )
 class MAZE_API URunner : public UActorComponent
 {
     GENERATED_BODY()

 public:    
     // Sets default values for this component's properties
     URunner(); 


 protected:
     // Called when the game starts
     virtual void BeginPlay() override;

 public:    
     // Called every frame
     virtual void TickComponent(float DeltaTime, ELevelTick TickType, FActorComponentTickFunction* ThisTickFunction) override;

     void IsNearToDoor();
     void IsNearToLampKey();

 private:
     void SetupComponents();

     UDoor Door;
     AActor* Runner = nullptr;
 };
```

Comment: Do you mean "custom"? "Costume" means something different.

Comment: ohhhh, that's right , sorry :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could be with this line in `Runner.h`:

```
UDoor Door;
```

In this case, the constructor, `UDoor()`, from `Door.h` is being called to initialize the default value of the private variable, `Door` in `Runner.h`. However, `Runner.h` may not have access to all of the includes and variables required by the `UDoor()` constructor. *I can't be sure if this is the case because you haven't posted the constructor code from your `Runner.cpp` file.*

Try making the variable `Door` in `Runner.h` a pointer instead, like this:

```
UDoor* Door;
```

To further clean up the code, you might use a sort of forward declaration by using the `class` keyword like this:

```
class UDoor* Door;
```

If you use forward declaration like this, you could remove `#include Door.h` from your `Runner.h` file and add it to your `Runner.cpp` file instead.

Comment: Thanks @DerpKat for your response..
That's right, i noticed that the problem is in UDoor Door;
I will try using UDoor as pointer and tell you the results .. keeping in touch :)

Comment: But how i can instantiate the object using pointer (UDoor* Door) ?

Comment: Try this in your constructor in the `Runnner.cpp` file: `Door = CreateDefaultSubobject<UDoor>(TEXT("NameYourDoorHere"));`

Comment: Thanks a lot DerpKat :)
Nice code brother

Comment: I want to ask you another question because i'm new c++ coder :)
Can i use NewObject rather than CreateDefaultSubobject?

Comment: If you use `NewObject`, you would have to do more work such as manually calling `RegisterComponent`. Using `CreateDefaultSubobject` is used for creation during construction. It should be noted that you should use `CreateComponent` for creation outside the constructor. Further reading here: https://forums.unrealengine.com/development-discussion/c-gameplay-programming/23132-what-is-the-correct-way-to-create-and-add-components-at-runtime